# Python 2.7 time delay word by word

Tags: python

```
import sys
import time
from random import randrange

words = ''' this is a cool delay typing program,
right now it print string by string.

I need to know how to make it print a word by word.'''

for i in words:
    sys.stdout.write(i)
    sys.stdout.flush()
    seconds = ".8" + str(randrange(1,5,2))
    seconds = float(seconds)
    time.sleep(seconds)
```

Comment: I don't see it printing *anything*.

Comment: yes it does I just recheck it. it delays for .8 sec.

Comment: It would be more accurate to say that your program prints character by character, since a string can be of any length (including zero).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make your life easier by making your string a list and then just adding a space as you print each word in your iteration. Like this:

When you are iterating over words, just use `split` to make it a list. Then inside your `stdout.write` just add a space after each word.

Modifications made in your code. This should work:

```
import sys
import time
from random import randrange

words = ''' this is a cool delay typing program,
right now it print string by string.

I need to know how to make it print a word by word.'''

for i in words.split():
    sys.stdout.write("{} ".format(i))
    sys.stdout.flush()

    seconds = ".8" + str(randrange(1,5,2))
    seconds = float(seconds)
    time.sleep(seconds)
```

Comment: Thank you ... How do I close this question ?

Comment: @JJse No idea. I never asked a question before. :P

Comment: @JJse: There's no need to close this question... other people may wish to contribute new answers. ;) But by accepting an answer you have indicated that your question has been answered to your satisfaction, so it's less likely to attract further answers.

Answer (score 0):

The code in idjaw's answer is the straight-forward way to do this, but it converts every whitespace sequence into a single space. My code preserves the original whitespace characters, i.e., any sequences of multiple spaces in the source string are printed as is, as well as things like newlines and tabs.

To split the source string appropriately using standard `str` methods is a little messy, so instead I used the [`re`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) module.

```
import sys
from time import sleep
import re

words = ''' This is a cool delay typing program.
It used to print character by character...

But now it prints word by word. '''    

def delay_typer(words, delay=0.8, stream=sys.stdout):
    tokens = re.findall(r'\s*\S+\s*', words)
    for s in tokens:
        stream.write(s)
        stream.flush()
        sleep(delay)

delay_typer(words)
delay_typer('I hope\nyou\tlike it. :)\n', 0.2)
```

I dropped the random stuff: I don't think there's much point to adding a random delay of 1 or 3 hundredths of a second.